# emplace_back an object containing a mutex

Tags: c++, constructor, mutex

I'm trying to create a vector of threads that perform a search. This is the important stuff from my `SearchThread` class.

```
class SearchThread {

        explicit SearchThread(int t_id) {
            id = t_id;
            run = true;

            thread = std::jthread([&]{
                while(run){
                    {
                        std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
                        cnd_var.wait(lock, [&] { return !run; });
                        if(!run) { return; }
                    }
                    Search();
                }
            });
        }
        
       void Search();

        int id;
        bool run;
        std::jthread thread;
        std::condition_variable cnd_var;
        std::mutex mtx;
}
```

And i'm attempting to construct them like this.

```
        std::vector<SearchThread> search_threads;
        for (int t_id = 0; t_id < num_threads; t_id++) {
            search_threads.emplace_back(t_id);
        }
```

The error i'm getting is `no matching function for call to 'construct_at'`. The issue i believe is with `std::mutex` and `std::conditional_variable`. I can have the mutex and conditional variable declared as pointers and then construct them on the heap in the class constructor, however that seems very ugly to me.

I guess my question is, why am i not allowed to do it like this, and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::mutex` is not copyable. Its copy constructor is deleted. "Copying a mutex" makes no logical sense. If the mutex is locked, what does that mean? Is the copy-constructed mutex is also locked? If so, who locked it? Who gets to unlock it?

This makes the `SearchThread` class also uncopyable, and have a deleted copy constructor. Since one of its members is an uncopyable `std::mutex`, that pretty much puts a kibosh on copy-ability of a `SearchThread`, too.

`std::vector` requires its contents to be copyable. One of `std::vector`'s proud achievements is that it will automatically copy the values in the vector, as needed, when it grows. This requires its contents to be copyable. `SearchThread` is not copyable. You cannot put it into a vector. It doesn't matter how you try to put it, `emplace_back`, or some other way. `reserve()` won't help you. A `std::vector` must contain a copyable class, there is no workaround for that.

Your options are:

1. Provide a user-defined copy constructor for your `SearchThread`, that implements whatever it means for a `SearchThread` to be copy-constructed from another instance of `SearchThread`. Perhaps its sufficient to copy all of its other members, and just have the copy-constructed `SearchThread` default-construct its mutex. You also have to provide a user-defined assignment operator as well. Or implement user-defined move constructor and assignment operator. The bottom line is: somehow make your `SearchThread` copyable/movable/assignable.
2. Use some other container that does not require a copyable object, like `std::list` perhaps.

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) the requirements on the value type have been relaxed a bit, so strictly speaking it doesn't _require_ the elements to be copyable. For instance I think you could still have it merely be noexcept move-constructible.

Comment: Well, you also have to have it assignable as well, that's the other important bit. Updated.

Comment: Note that neither a condition_variable nor a mutex is move-constructible, but a jthread is.